# Temporary entitlements to call AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

When I call AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions in a sandboxed program the dialog to request permission does not open and I get "sandbox deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarn" error in the console.

If I add a temporary entitlement com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name for com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarn the error goes away and the dialog appears. This doesn't make any sense however that should I need this entitlement to simply ask the user for their permission and I suspect it will get rejected from the AppStore.

Does anyone know if what I'm doing is correct?

Comment: An update on this. I did in fact get rejected from the App Store without any further explanation or guidance. This still makes no sense and Apple isn't being very helpful.